# Python dict assignment returns same answer for two different queries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a super simple program that im parsing for score and time data.

```
orig = https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2017/leaderboards
```

orig equals the output of that API call I was using it as a pasted in value for this example. It would have been overly huge to paste it in here for the orig value

```
default_score = {1: '--',
             2: '--',
             3: '--',
             4: '--',
             5: '--',
             6: '--'}
for i in range(50):
    time = default_score
    rank = default_score
    print orig[0]['athletes'][i]['name']
    for j in range(2):
        time[j] = orig[0]['athletes'][i]['scores'][j]['scoredetails']['time']
        rank[j]= orig[0]['athletes'][i]['scores'][j]['workoutrank']

print rank
print time
```

I cant figure out why i dont get unique values for rank and time.

my result is

```
Mathew Fraser
{0: '20', 1: '15', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
{0: '20', 1: '15', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
Richard Froning Jr.
{0: '26', 1: '16', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
{0: '26', 1: '16', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
Noah Ohlsen
{0: '50', 1: '5', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
{0: '50', 1: '5', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
Marcelo Bruno
{0: '37', 1: '37', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
{0: '37', 1: '37', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
....
```

[api call](https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2017/leaderboards)

Comment: Try using the Python debugger, 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()'

Comment: You haven't made a copy of the dict, you just have two different references to the same dict.

Comment: Do the 'time' and 'rank' variables not capture the out put of the references?

Comment: do `default_score.copy()` in order to create new instances of your dict with every iteration. Cf. https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both time and rank are pointing to the same default_score dictionary. You need to make a copy of the default dictionary. See the example below

```
default_score = {1: '--',
             2: '--',
             3: '--',
             4: '--',
             5: '--',
             6: '--'}
rank = default_score
time = default_score
#if I modify rank dictionary, even time is modified to the same value
rank[1]=5
print rank
print time
```

results in

```
{1: 5, 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
{1: 5, 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
```

But when

```
default_score = {1: '--',
             2: '--',
             3: '--',
             4: '--',
             5: '--',
             6: '--'}

rank_copy = default_score.copy()
time_copy = default_score.copy()
rank_copy[1] = 5
print rank_copy
print time_copy
```

results in

```
{1: 5, 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
{1: '--', 2: '--', 3: '--', 4: '--', 5: '--', 6: '--'}
```

Comment: You sir have solved. It was a super easy solution. Thank you!!  I guess both lines were pointing to the same dictionary and had to be told explicitly to copy it.